# How to add columns from different sheets in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have such data in 35 excel sheets ( Sheet 1 to sheet 35) at the same position

[image]

I want to  add all the second columns and get total Range combining all files.  So if there are two such files and in the second file  0..32% is 5, then after combining I should get 0..32% 5+2=7. And  so On.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the formula `=SUM(FirstSheetName:LastSheetName!CellNumber)`
Create a new sheet and copy your first column (Range) as it is.
Select the cell in your next column (No. of Students) where you start your entries and type the formula in your formula bar and hit enter.
Then use the drag to fill option to drag and fill the remaining cells.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]
[image: Image 4]